# Sort recycler view in MVVM architecture

Tags: android, sorting, mvvm, android-recyclerview, android-room

I have a recycler view implemented in MVVM architecture with room database. Created this query to sort recycler view in DAO file.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM task_table ORDER BY " +
            "CASE WHEN:choice =1 THEN date END ASC," +
            "CASE WHEN:choice=2 THEN title END ASC")
    fun readAllData(choice : Int): LiveData<MutableList<Task>>
```

Repository file

```
class TaskRepository(private val taskDao: TaskDao) {
    val readAllData: LiveData<MutableList<Task>> = taskDao.readAllData(1)

    suspend fun addTask(task: Task) {
        taskDao.addTask(task)
    }

    suspend fun deleteTask(task: Task) {
        taskDao.deleteTask(task)
    }

    suspend fun updateTask(task: Task) {
        taskDao.updateTask(task)
    }

    fun deleteAllTasks() {
        taskDao.deleteAllTasks()
    }
}
```

ViewModel file

```
class TaskViewModel(
    application: Application,
) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    val readAllData: LiveData<MutableList<Task>>
    private val repository: TaskRepository

    init {
        val taskDao = TaskDatabase.getDatabase(application).taskDao()
        repository = TaskRepository(taskDao)
        readAllData = repository.readAllData
    }

    fun addTask(task: Task) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.addTask(task)
        }
    }

    fun updateTask(task: Task) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.updateTask(task)
        }
    }

    fun deleteTask(task: Task) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.deleteTask(task)
        }
    }

    fun deleteAllTask() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.deleteAllTasks()
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to implement the sort menu in UI in order to make my room database sort in attributes. Which means I want to pass data from Fragment to Repository file so that DAO can take parameter.

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't want to use `MutableList` with `LiveData`. If you would just add/remove from the value that is in the LiveData the underlying object is not changed and you won't get updates from it.

The most common approach(AFAIK) is to have `LiveData` of the thing that modifies your query. With combination of `Transformations.switchMap` you can use the output of one LiveData and translate it into another `LiveData`(your query).

```
class TaskViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val taskDao: TaskDatabase.getDatabase(application).taskDao()
    private val repository: TaskRepository = TaskRepository(taskDao)

    private val _filter: MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData(1)
    val filter: LiveData<Int>
        get() = _filter

    private val _data: MutableLiveData<List<Task>> = Transformations.switchMap(filter) { choice ->
        repository.readAllData(choice)
    }
    val readAllData: LiveData<List<Task>>
        get() = _data

    fun updateFilter(filter: Int) {
        _filter.postValue(filter)
    }
}
```

Any change in `_filter` will trigger re-evaluaing via the `switchMap` which will get `readAllData` from your `repository`.